# Bypass Incapsula JStest

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to update my status using cURL on a website  that uses Incapsula.
I can not even access the main page, because of their JS test security.
I am cloning my headers, useragent, IP and still I get the error.

So can anyone come up with a way to get cURL to connect? Here is my code, which works great for all other sites:

```
function curl_redirect_exec($ch, &$redirects, $curlopt_header = false) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302) {
        list($header) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        $matches = array();
        preg_match('/(Location:|URI:)(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
        $url = trim(array_pop($matches));
        $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
        if (isset($url_parsed)) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            $redirects++;
            return curl_redirect_exec($ch, $redirects);
        }
    }
    if ($curlopt_header)
        return $http_code.$data;
    else {
        list(,$body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2);
        return $http_code.$body;
    }
}
function getPage($url,$post=false,$cookijs=false) {
if(!$cookijs) $cookijs = "pass=71c2bce341575e4312fcf19ce2a6eaa9;uid=1174461";
$cookie = tempnam ("/tmp/curlcookies", "CURLCOOKIE");
$timeout = 10;
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.enjin.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300',
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
));
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
  #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:' ) );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookijs);
 if((isset($post)) && ($post != false)) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }     
 $redirects=5000;
 $data = curl_redirect_exec($ch,$redirects);

 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
$cookijs = array(
"incap_ses_151_48573 " => "eygjTe/9pTa4mxn7Vn0YAkzw51IAAAAAeowsmkMHrBX5eKy0Ejmh8g==",
"visid_incap_48573" => "4E8wP8B5QfKxV6UcDRpmXzHw51IAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACAeLthAV1yLUSyWQXQRO15b5GpU/fLrOMW"
);
$lapa = getPage("http://www.enjin.com", false, $cookijs
);
echo $lapa;
```

Comment: It can't be done via Curl since Incapsula is testing you JS first - JS is executed on browser and curl can't - you should use phyton or C# and create a batch file that will receive you status and update - then you can execute it using shell_exec - if you need more help and that's is important to you contact me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you contact enjin and ask them to whitelist your ip or somethin'...
it'll save you time, useless efforts and getting banned.